# How do I convert a cell to RFC 3986 standard (URLEncoded) in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, url, google-sheets-custom-function

Is it possible to convert text from a certain cell to RFC 3986 (http://url-encoder.org/) in a Google Spreadsheet?
Lets say `C4` has the value `John Doe`, then `D4` must be `John%20Doe`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, you can create a custom function for that.

Click *Tools → Script Editor*. Select *Create blank project*.

In the script editor window, paste the following code:

```
function encode(value) {
  return encodeURIComponent(value);
}
```

Save the script (give it a name if prompted), and return to your spreadsheet.

Now, you may use the function as `=encode`. If your `C4` cell contains the text `John Doe`, enter the following in your `D4` cell: `=encode(C4)`.

`D4` should now display `John%20Doe`.

I have created [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16ENqfFTUCZ8fT60L1dFARfRtqhKNSTefO-yX9zT3QMA/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate.

Comment: This was an excellent answer when it was given. There is now a native function `=ENCODEURL` within Sheets for this ([see below](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119324/90261)).

Answer (score 6):

For other's reference - a similar method also works for decode.

```
function decode(value) {
  return decodeURIComponent(value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without a custom function using `ENCODEURL`.

eg:

```
=hyperlink(
  ENCODEURL(A1)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

For others who are still searching for this, Google Sheets has a function called ENCODEURL now (Aug 2018), so you don't need to make your own any more.

Comment: Wish I'd seen this first!

Comment: but no decode! wtf?